# Changing the "Press any key to Continue..." in C++ using Visual Basics

Tags: c++, keyboard

For every program we've wrote so far in class it ends with the default "Press any key to continue..." How do I change this? I've tried using

cout<< "Press any key to end the program";
system("pause>"nul)

But it still displays "press any key to continue" one I enter a key. Any ideas?

Here's what I have thus far (feel free to point out how I can improve in other areas as well!)
        `

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //Declaring my varibles
    double persons = 0;
    double tier1 = 125;
    double tier2 = 100;
    double tier3 = 75;
    double cost = 0;
    string hyphens = "";
    system("cls");
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------- " << endl;
    cout << "Computer Programming Seminar" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------- " << endl<<endl;
    cout << "Please enter the number of registrants: ";
    cin >> persons;
    cout << hyphens << endl;
    if (0 < persons && persons < 6)
        cost = persons * tier1;

    else if (5 < persons && persons < 21)
        cost = persons *tier2;

    else if (persons >= 21)
        cost = persons*tier3;
    else
    {
        cost = 0;
        cout << "Invalid Entry" <<endl << endl;
    }

    cout << "Total Amount Owed for the Seminar: $" << cost << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------- " << endl;
    cout << endl << endl << "Press any key to end the Seminar Program";
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

My pattern is:

```
std::cout << "Paused. Press Enter to continue.";
std::cin.ignore(100000, '\n');
```

You can change the prompt to whatever you want.

Comment: I just use `std::cin.get()` instead, usually works fine.

Answer (score 1):

*Press any key to continue...* it's default value and it's never changes. You can try `#include <conio.h>` and Instead of `system("pause");` Use:

```
_getch();
```

Comment: That is the C way of doing it.  The C++ way is `std::cin.get()` or related `std::cin` I/O

Answer (score 0):

The message you want to avoid does not come from your program at all.  It comes from the `pause` command.  So, if you want to avoid the message, don't call `system("pause")` anymore.  Do your own I/O in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the console foreground and background color to black after using Console.WriteLine to display a custom ending message

It looks slightly sloppy to have the cursor dangling out in midair, but it's also super easy and won't really cause issues.